# Wake On Lan not working on AsRock motherboard

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, wakeonlan

I'm trying to get Wake On Lan to work on my Ubuntu server (16.04.7 LTS).
I have an AsRock G31M-GS

1. I have set WoL on my BIOS
2. I have enabled WoL (method g) on eth0
3. I have added a script so that eth0 stays as g on startup.

I can confirm that eth0 stays as g after reboot.

But after shutdown the lights on the network card are off.
Right now WOL is working only if i suspend (`pm-suspend`) the pc.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After countless hours of thinkering i got a solution.
Even though everything sotware-wise was enabled i needed to make a fix hardware-wise.
Looking at the motherboard manual i saw there was a jumper setting to disable EuP:
[jumper setting from manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xh1L.png)

With EuP disabled, WoL was finally available.

If after booting the network card is down (`Failed to start Raise network interfaces`) you need to "reset" it with this script([source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=543803&sid=9eff68bc768cae5a930179287b587395#p543803)) after every boot:

```
#!/bin/sh
# e.g. rtl_up.sh eth0

ETHDEV=$1
modprobe -r r8168
modprobe r8168 speed=100 duplex=1 autoneg=0
ethtool $ETHDEV | grep detect
ifconfig $ETHDEV up && mii-tool -F 100baseTx-FD $ETHDEV
ethtool $ETHDEV | grep detect
dhclient $ETHDEV
ifconfig $ETHDEV
ethtool -s $ETHDEV wol g
exit 0
```

Save it in a file, make it executable and add this line in `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service` after the `ExecStart` line:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash /path/to/script
```

Reboot.